Difference between llm and chat llm in langchain
I have been trying to figure out the difference between LLM and chat LLM in langchain. I understand that chat LLM seems to have a bunch of methods that make it more friendly for chat applications. I have also found on Langchain's documentation:

Both llm and chat_model are objects that represent configuration for a particular model. You can initialize them with parameters like temperature and others, and pass them around. The main difference between them is their input and output schemas. The LLM objects take string as input and output string. The ChatModel objects take a list of messages as input and output a message.

But when I test a chain feeding in a list of messages into a normal LLM, it seems to work. The difference in output schema still shows but input schema doesn't seem to matter. Is this expected behavior?
P.S: I am using OllamaLLM() and ChatOllama()

The difference is similar to ChatOpenAI vs OpenAI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78263473/19123103. One is a text completions model that takes a string in and spits out a string while the other is a chat completions model that takes a list of messages in and spits out a message. Similar to langchain_openai, I think the text completions models are being deprecated.

There is also LM at least in logs as of such process namely DictationIM: Error creating language model from text: '... []', Command Parsing Error: Empty optional phrase starting at ]. An optional phrase must contain one or more characters. And probably intentions in some Google product are also in a line to this one.
